# Difference between preprocessor directive #if and normal if

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

What is difference between preprocessor directive `#if` and normal `if` in **C**? I'm new to **C**.

Comment: Are you asking what the preprocessor does?  Are you asking how it works?  What are you really asking?

Comment: I want to know how the preprocessor does !!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Statements with # in front of them are called preprocessor directives. They are processed by a parser before the code is actually compiled. From the first search hit using Google (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/):

> Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of our programs that are not program statements but directives for the preprocessor. These lines are always preceded by a hash sign (#). The preprocessor is executed before the actual compilation of code begins, therefore the preprocessor digests all these directives before any code is generated by the statements.

So a #if will be decided at compile time, a "normal" if will be decided at run time. In other words,

```
#define TEST 1
#if TEST
printf("%d", TEST);
#endif
```

Will compile as

```
printf("%d", 1);
```

If instead you wrote

```
#define TEST 1
if(TEST)
printf("%d", TEST);
```

The program would actually compile as

```
if(1)
printf("%d", 1);
```

Comment: so we can use whatever we want ?

Comment: @kevin No. Specifically `int x=1; #if X==1` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor `if` allows you to condition the code before it's sent to the compiler. Often used to stop header code from being added twice.

edit, did you mean C++, because it was tagged as such?
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/110-a-first-look-at-the-preprocessor/

Comment: Stopping header code from being added twice is a very limited and even esoteric use of the preprocessor ... hardly "normally".

Comment: @Jim Balter Based on the original question, kevin and others likely to find these answers likely saw it first in code as header guards...

Comment: There's no basis for that claim. In fact, it's extremely unlikely from the original question.

Comment: @ Jim Balter here's a basis: When I first saw them, and wondered whats the difference between `#if` and `if` was, it was in someone else's source

Comment: So that's about you, not about "kevin and others". I stand by my statement.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor if is handled by the preprocessor as the first step in the program being compiled.  The normal if is handled at runtime when the program is executed.  The preprocessor directive is used to enable conditional compilation, using different sections of the code depending on different defined preprocessor constants/expressions.  The normal if is used to control flow in the executing program.