# "if " and " #if "; which one is better to use

Tags: c, if-statement

I learned that `if` or `#if` can both be used for condition checks.
As we can check conditions using `if`, why would we use preprocessor `#if`?

What difference will it make to my code if I use `#if` instead of `if`?

Which one is better to use and why?

Comment: Lookup "preprocessor".

Comment: I don't understand the -1s. While totally noobish, this is a pretty valid question. And not that easily googlable if you don't know "preprocessor" keyword.

Comment: I don't understand the "close as not constructive" votes: this is a somewhat simple but completely legitimate question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, It's awful that someone don't see difference between runtime and preprocessor...

Comment: @Eddy_Em: We were all new to this stuff once.

Comment: @Dariusz the OP does know the word preprocessor (see the question), and this question is not suitable for the site. The fact that everyone asked this question in his/her noobish days doesn't matter at all. Also, OP doesn't have to search for [preprocessor to find the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176065/difference-between-preprocessor-directive-if-and-normal-if).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I suspect "which is better" causes a reflex, close as not constructive.

Comment: @Krishnabharda Since you found a duplicate, you should flag the post as duplicate and possibly add a comment, so that people won't waste their time answering this question.

Comment: @Dariusz I can't.. I already flagged it as **not constructive**, which  also applies in this case I think.

Comment: @Dariusz Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: IMHO this is far more constructive than all the *"omg *scanf doesn't work when I give it random arguments without reading the spec"* questions that users leave open every week, sometimes upvoting it. It looks more like a duplicate to me, but the question itself seems reasonable.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`if` and `#if` are different things with different purposes.

If you use the `if` statement, the condition is evaluated at runtime, and the code for both branches exists within the compiled program. The condition can be based on runtime information, such as the state of a variable. `if` is for standard flow control in a program.

If you use the preprocessor's `#if`, the condition is evaluated at compile-time (originally this was *before* compile-time, but these days the preprocessor is usually part of the compiler), and the code for the false branch is **not** included in the compiled program. The condition can only be based on compile-time information (such as `#define` constants and the like). `#if` is for having different code for different compile-time environments (for instance, different code for compiling on Windows vs. *nix, that sort of thing).

Answer (score 15):

we could not say which better to use, because one is used in the compilation phase (`#if`) and the other one is used in the runtime phase(`if`)

```
#if 1
   printf("this code will be built\n");
#else
   printf("this code will not\n");
#endif
```

try to build the above code with `gcc -E` and you will see that your compiler will generate another code containing only :

```
printf("this code will be build\n");
```

the other printf will not be present in the new code (pre processor code) and then no present in the program binary.

Conclusion: the `#if` is treated in the compilation phase but the normal `if` is treated when your program run

You can use the `#if 0` in a part of your code inorder to avoid the compiler to compile it. it's like you have commented this part

example

```
int main(void) {

       printf("this code will be build\n");
#if 0
       printf("this code will not\n");
#endif

}
```

it's equivalent to

```
int main(void) {

       printf("this code will be built\n");
/*
       printf("this code will not\n");
*/

}
```

Comment: "one is used in the compilation phase (#if) and the other one is used in the compilation phase (if)" ;)

Comment: @MichalB. it's typo :)

Answer (score 7):

Hey both are different

1. `#if` Tests if the condition is true at the compile time.
2. `if` is evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You should use #if when the outcome of the condition is known at compile time and regular if when outcome is not known until runtime.

```
#if DEBUG
```

I know at compile time I am making a debug build

```
if (date == DateTime.Today)
```

Depends on what day it is

Answer (score 3):

Some uses of `#if` are:

- You want to put extra prints, or checks when you build a debug version of your code
- you want to ensure the compiler doesn't include a .h file twice
- you want to write code that will use different system calls, and depending on the system it gets compiled on use the appropriate ones.

Because all of the above are checked at compile time this means that:

- The condition must be able to be evaluated at compiletime
- The produced code will not contain the branches that evaluate to false, leading to smaller code, and faster, as the condition is not checked every time the program is run.

Examples:

Adding extra checks only for debug mode:

```
#define DEBUGLEVEL 2

#if DEBUGLEVEL > 1
   printf("The value of x is: %d", x);
#end if

#if DEBUGLEVEL > 2
   printf("The address of x is: %x", &x);
   ASSERT(x > 100);
#end if
```

Ensuring header only gets included once:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
   class Person{
        ....
   };
#end if
```

Having different code depending on platform:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
   time = QueryPerformanceCounter(..);
#else
   time = gettimeofday(..);
#endif
```